# prove that for any graph X(G') is equal or more than $\alpha(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

an independent set of G is a subset of V(G) in which no one of that vertices are connected to each other.
we define $\alpha(G)$ as maximum size of an independent set of graph G.
and also we define X(G) as minimum number of colors that we need for a vertex coloring of G in which every two connected vertices have different colors ( proper vertex coloring ) .
now ... proof that X(G') is equal or more than $\alpha(G)$ . 
notice that G' is complement of G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prove is pretty easy. Notice the following
 $$\omega(G)\leq \chi(G) $$
where $\omega(G)$ is the clique number (*i.e.* size of the largest clique in $G$, -or complete subgraph in $G$-)
We have 
 $$\omega(G)= \alpha(G^c) $$
Then  $$\alpha(G^c) \leq \chi(G) $$
If $H =G^c$, then $$\alpha(H) \leq \chi(H^c) $$

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade You're welcome man